# Cloning tr to add new item and replacing a select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Had a code where i had to clone the respected tr and create the new one, but the tr has the column which has a select and that selection has one value which when chosen converts the select box into the textbox and then whe i click add item, it adds another text text, i knowwhy it is hapening, because i am just cloning it.

how can i fix it, i am bit confused

here is my code

```
<table>
<tr><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div id="stlineitems">
              <label for="stlineitems">Item(s)</label></td>
            <td><div class="onlyleft">
                <select name="get_Items" id="get_Items" class="selectItemsList" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Choose Item">
                  <option></option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="moveboxleft">
                <select name="getSelection" class="form-control getSelectedprice">
                    <optgroup label="Class Price">

                        <option value="160.0000">$160.00</option>

                    </optgroup>

                    <optgroup label="Custom Price">
                        <option value="0">$0</option>
                        <option value="-2">My Price</option>
                        <option value="-1">Custom Price</option>
                    </optgroup>
                </select>
              </div><div class="moveboxleftinput" style="display:none;">
                <input type="text" name="getSelection" value="" class="form-control">
              </div>
              <br/>
              <div class="nextitem"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="createNewItemTag">Add Item</a></div></td>
              </div>
          </tr>
    </table>


    $('.createNewItemTag').click(function(){
        var obj = $(this).parents('tr').first();
        var clonedObj = $(obj[0].outerHTML);
        clonedObj.find(".select2-container").remove();
        clonedObj.find('.createNewItemTag').remove();
        clonedObj.find('td').last().append("<a class='removeItem' href='javascript:void(0);'>Remove</a>");
        clonedObj.find(".removeItem").click(function(){
            $(this).parents('tr').first().remove();
        }); 
        obj.before(clonedObj);
        initSelect2ForNextItem(clonedObj.find(".selectItemsList").first());
    });

    $(document).on('change','.getSelectedprice',function() {
        if ($('.getSelectedprice option:selected').text() == "Custom Price"){
            $('.moveboxleft').hide();
            $('.moveboxleftinput').show();
        }else {
            $('.moveboxleft').show();
            $('.moveboxleftinput').hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: There is no `tr` parent of the element `$('.createNewItemTag')` ... his is why `var obj = $(this).parents('tr').first();`  will returns null and you HTML isnt valid too.

Comment: i had updated my code

Comment: 1- html still invalid, the div is inside the `td` element so you have to close it before `td` closes --> `<td><div id="stlineitems">
              <label for="stlineitems">Item(s)</label></div></td>`   2-you are using an undefined function `initSelect2ForNextItem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have some improperly nested HTML that should be fixed.

But as for the cloning. My advice is to never clone an item after it has been instrumented with any event handlers or other plugins (like Select2). The way to avoid that is to do the following:

1. Clone the row right away at page load (before registering event handlers and instrumenting).
2. Whenever you need a new row, clone the original clone. That way you still have the original clone to re-clone over and over.
3. Use event delegation as much as possible to register event handlers.
4. If you need to instrument any of the elements on a newly added row, do it after you have inserted it into the page.

In your case, you could have this:

```
var $table = $('table');

var $CLONED_ROW = $table.find('tbody>tr:first').clone();
$CLONED_ROW.find('.createNewItemTag').replaceWith(
    '<a class="removeItem" href="#">Remove</a>');

$table.on('click', '.createNewItemTag', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr'),
        $newRow = $CLONED_ROW.clone();
    $newRow.insertBefore($row);
    //initSelect2ForNextItem($newRow.find('.selectItemsList'));
});

$table.on('click', '.removeItem', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
}); 

$table.on('change', '.getSelectedprice', function() {
    var $select = $(this),
        $row = $select.closest('tr');
    if ($select.val() == '-1') {
        $row.find('.moveboxleft').hide();
        $row.find('.moveboxleftinput').show();
    } else {
        $row.find('.moveboxleft').show();
        $row.find('.moveboxleftinput').hide();
    }
});

//initSelect2ForNextItem($table.find('.selectItemsList'));
```

Notice the placement of the calls to `initSelect2ForNextItem()`.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/un8abjjn/8/)

A few more things:

1. You can use `.closest()`, instead of `.parents().first()`.
2. When you hide/show the text input, you need to limit it to the current row.
3. It is better to use the value of a select element, rather than the text.

Comment: fiddle is not working, if i choose custom price, it is not converting the select into the input field

Comment: @Daniel - I updated the fiddle and the answer. Try again.

Comment: @Daniel - Was this not helpful?

Comment: it was, i forgot to mark your answer as select. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid. For example, you haven't closed the first div in your first td tag:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div id="stlineitems">
            <label for="stlineitems">Item(s)</label>
        <!-- Close div should go here -->
    </td>
```

Try correcting your HTML and re-evaluate your code, then resubmit if you are still having problems.